# Find the highest and low value of a table

Tags: javascript

I am not getting the correct result with this code and I am not sure why.  The coded should go through the table one row at a time and collect the value and the id. if the retrieved value is higher/lower than current high/low it set a field in the another table (which works). The function is executed every time value is added to the table through a form.

Example of result set I am getting:

```
input   total   Highest Lowest
Test 1          
1           1000       1      1
2           2000       1      2
3            500       1      2
 Test 2         
1            500       1      1
2           2000       1      2
3           1000       3      2
```

And the code.

```
function calHiLow() {
var i;
var tableSet = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var tBody = tableSet[0].tBodies[0];
var noRows = tBody.rows.length;
var row;
var cell;
var iEntryValueCell;
var iEntryValueChildNode;
var iEntryValueNodeValue;
var iEntryValue;
var iEntryNoCell;
var iEntryNoChildNode;
var iEntryNo;

//go through each row and check the total value
for (i = 0; i < noRows; i++) {

    //get the first row
    row = tBody.rows[i];

    //get the row cell of the total column
    iEntryValueCell = row.cells[5];

   //get the node of the current total node
    iEntryValueChildNode = iEntryValueCell.childNodes[0];

    //get the value of the current total cell
    iEntryValueNodeValue = iEntryValueChildNode.nodeValue;

    //remove the $ from the value
    iEntryValue = iEntryValueNodeValue.substring(1);

   // get the row cell of the Entry No column
    iEntryNoCell = row.cells[0];

   // get the value of the current Entry No Node
    iEntryNoChildNode = iEntryNoCell.childNodes[0];

    // get the value of the current Entry No cell
    iEntryNo = iEntryNoChildNode.nodeValue;

    chkLowest(iEntryValue, iEntryNo);
    chkHighest(iEntryValue, iEntryNo);
    }
}

function chkLowest(low, EntryNo) {
if (low < LowestValue || LowestValue == null) {
    LowestValue = low;
    setLowEntry(EntryNo); 
}
}

function chkHighest(high, EntryNo) {
if (high > highestValue ||highestValue == null) {
    highestValue = high;
    setHighEntry(EntryNo); 
}
}
```

Global variables

```
var highestValue;
var LowestValue;
```

Any thoughts?

it is pulling a string I add a parseFloat and have the same issue.

the table is dynamically create when the user adds an new value here is the function

```
function addRow() {
var i;
var aLen = newLoan.length;
var content;
var tableSet = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var table = tableSet[0].tBodies[0];
var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);


for (i = 0; i < aLen ; i++) {
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    content = document.createTextNode(newEntry[i]);
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    newCell.appendChild(content);
}

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
newRow.appendChild(newCell);
var btn = document.createElement('button');
newCell.appendChild(btn);
text = document.createTextNode('Remove');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'pure-button');
btn.setAttribute('value', loanNo);
btn.appendChild(text);
```

}

the data does add to the table correctly and the calHiLow() does pull the correct information.  where it seem to be having issue is on the chk's

Comment: Somewhat hard to follow along, but what are the types of the values you're getting? I'm not 100% sure, but pulling data from HTML should give you strings, which obviously wouldn't compare like numbers.

Comment: do you have a sample of the raw html table that you are using?